# sstream using input and output file

Tags: c++

So i have a file data3.txt which basically looks like this:

```
#file:data.txt
#data inputs
1 1234 +0.2 23.89 6.21
2 132 -0.03 3.22 0.1
3    32 0.00 31.50   4.76
```

And I want to take the first 3 columns to write into a new file using stringtreams

```
#include <cctype>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  string line;
  float curr_price, change;
  int stock_number;
  ifstream fin("data3.txt");
  istringstream iss;
  ostringstream oss;
  if(!fin){
    cerr<<"Can't open a file";
  }
  ofstream outfile("data2.txt");
  while (getline(fin,line)){
    iss.clear();
    iss.str(line);
    iss>>stock_number>>curr_price>>change;
    while(isspace(iss.peek()))
      iss.ignore();
    while(iss.str() == "#")
      iss.ignore();
    if( iss.str()==""){
      break;
    }
    oss<<stock_number<<"\t"<<curr_price<<"\t"<<change<<"\n";
    outfile<<oss.str();
  }
}
```

but i my output file looks nasty:

```
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
1   1234    0.2
0   0   0
0   0   0
1   1234    0.2
2   132 -0.03
0   0   0
0   0   0
1   1234    0.2
2   132 -0.03
3   32  0
```

I have no idea from where does zeros came from, and if i put the ofstream out of the while loop then it will only print the last data row

Comment: The zeroes seem to come from the comment rows but I don't know why the rows are repeated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that you always output numbers, even if you get a comment. Also, the peek and ignore stuff should not be necessary. To check whether the numbers were successfully read, simply evaluate the stream as a boolean after the read, like I do in this example:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    ifstream in(argv[1]);
    ofstream out(argv[2]);
    string line;
    while(getline(in,line))
    {
        if(line.empty() || line[0] == '#') continue;
        double number, price, change;
        stringstream ss(line);
        if(ss >> number >> price >> change)
            out << number << "\t" << price << "\t" << change << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is, by the way, an example of a case where using some C functions would make things both simpler and prettier:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    string line;
    int number;
    double price, change;
    while(getline(cin,line))
        if(sscanf(line.c_str(), "%d %lf %lf", &number, &price, &change)==3)
            printf("%3d %8.2f %8.2f\n", number, price, change);
    return 0;
}
```

This example uses standard input and output instead of files. These are called "standard" for a reason: They are very flexible, and can be redirected to/from files and other processes very simply. But the program would be very similar with files.

Comment: I just got one question how does this first implemenetation use ostringstream and istringstream?

Comment: It doesn't, so if that was critical I guess this isn't what you were looking for. The ostringstream is not necessary for what you were doing, so I didn't use it. The istringstream was useful due to its tokenizing properties. I used a plain stringstream, but it could have been replaced by an istringstream without any changes.

Comment: I was suppose to use the istringstream and ostringstream actually

Comment: i got the istringstream and ostringstream but if you could just explain what does this line do: if(ss >> number >> price >> change)

Comment: Sure. It reads the variables number, price and change from the stringstream ss, and then checks if the ss is in a valid state after this. If it is, it means that all three numbers were successfully read. If it is not, it means that there was some problem, such as the line having a # in it, or too few numbers, etc., in which case we skip the printing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to **always** check that your input was successful! Also, you rarely need to resort to strange character based reading techniques. For example, there is a manipulator to skip leading whitespace: `std::ws`. Below is a version which doesn't make much assumption about the types of the values. If the first value on a line has to be an integer, you can use `int` instead of `std::string` and you can even skip the check for the comment line! You'd just check that reading three values was successful.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream      in("input.txt");
    std::ofstream      out("output.txt");
    std::istringstream lin;
    std::string        tmp0, tmp1, tmp2;
    for (std::string line; std::getline(in, line); ) {
        lin.clear();
        lin.str(line);
        if ((lin >> std::ws).peek() != '#'
            && lin >> tmp0 >> tmp1 >> tmp2) {
            out << tmp0 << '\t' << tmp1 << '\t' << tmp2 << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```